# VBA - Get all value in Array as subsequent strings

Tags: sql, arrays, vba

I have connected VBA & SQL Database in order to pull information.
I have written a script that returns exactly what I want but I would like to make it dynamical (Change years used etc.) and I am here running into problems.

I need to have a special line in my SQL Query which only has 1 thing that changes between the lines (Number of lines need to change and  the Case when y.Date_Year = )

I get an Error message in the below code saying that there is a Type mismatch at the " & " sign right above my "period ()" array.

```
Sub test()
Dim SQLDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim sQuery As String
Dim info()
Dim Start_D As String
Dim End_D As String
Dim Numerator_Used As String
Dim Denominator_Used As String
Dim Number_Years As Integer
Dim period()

Numerator_Used = Range("Numerator")
Denominator_Used = Range("Denominator")
Start_D = Range("Start_Date")
End_D = Range("End_Date")

Range("A11:J100000").Cells.ClearContents

Number_Years = End_D - Start_D
ReDim period(Number_Years + 1)

For i = 0 To Number_Years
period(i + 1) = ",sum(case when y.date_year = " & Start_D + i & " then n." & Numerator_Used & " end) / sum(case when y.date_year = " & Start_D + i & " then s." & Denominator_Used & " end) as '" & Numerator_Used & "/" & Denominator_Used & " " & Start_D + i & "' & _ "
Next i


' Get Margin Expectation Changes
sQuery ="select m.date_month" & _
        " m.date_month " & _
        period() & _
        " from " & Numerator_Used & " as n" & _
        " inner join " & Denominator_Used & " as s on  s.company_id = n.company_id" & _
                              " and s.date_month_id = n.date_month_id" & _
                              " and s.date_year_id = n.date_year_id" & _
        " inner join date_year as y on y.date_year_id = n.date_year_id" & _
        " inner join date_month as m on m.date_month_id = n.date_month_id" & _
        " where y.date_year between " & Start_D & " and " & End_D & " " & _
        " and n." & Numerator_Used & " <> 0" & _
        " and s." & Denominator_Used & " <> 0" & _
        " group by m.date_month;"

Set rs = Common.SQL_Read(SQLDB, sQuery)


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11").CopyFromRecordset rs

Set SQLDB = Common.SQL_Close(SQLDB)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't explicit convert `period` data into string as it is an array of variant data type.You have to loop through these data, i.e.: `For i = LBound(period()) To UBound(period()) tmpstring = tmpstring & period(i) & "...." Next`

Comment: period will be an array, so `join(period,"")` perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the ocmment to the question, you can not explicity convert `period()` data into string as it is an array of variant data type (each undefined variable is treated as variant data type). You have to loop through the array data, i.e.:

```
For i = LBound(period()) To UBound(period())
    sQuery = sQuery &   period(i) & "...." 
Next
'finally:
sQuery = "SELECT ... " & sQuery & " ...."
```

Change the code as i mentioned above and let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you, it works for two periods but not for more so I'm guessing it has something to do with the length of the line or something similar (it all gets taken on a single line which might not work in sql?).

Anywho this correctly solved this problem, now I need to find the solution to this next problem

Comment: You're very welcome. For more details about data types, check this: [VBA Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/string-data-type)